# Gathering input using raw_input in Python

Tags: python, input, python-2.x

So I am trying to get input for a program using `raw_input` and I have:

```
def Input1(time):

    userInput = raw_input()
    print ("Please choose either morning or night: ")

    if userInput != "morning" or "night":
        print ("Invalid entry. Select again")
        Input1(time)

    if userInput in "morning" or "night":
        Input2(year)
```

The second `if` statement is prompting it to go onto more programming.

When I try to run this program, it runs and everything, but it doesn't ask user to input anything. any ideas?

and while it isn't showing, everything is tabbed over under the `def Input1(time):`

Comment: Are you calling `Input1` at all? And to indent, you need to use 4 spaces in front of every line of code, since that's the way you add code to a SO post.

Comment: `if userInput in "morning" or "night":` should be either `if userInput in ['morning, 'night']:` **or** `if userInput == 'morning' or userInput == 'night':`. As it stands now, the line is equivalent to `if userInput in 'morning' or 'night' == True:`, which of course always is true. (PS: `'mor' in 'morning' == True`)

Answer (score 1):

This code is bad for many reasons:

```
def Input1(time):
```

A function name should not start with an uppercase letter.

```
userInput = raw_input()
print ("Please choose either morning or night: ")
```

Simply write: userInuput = raw_input("Please choose either morning or night: ")

```
if userInput != "morning" or "night":
```

This is equivalent to:

```
if userInput != "morning" or True:
```

Which is always true...

```
    print ("Invalid entry. Select again")
    Input1(time)
```

And here, you do a recursive call, to ask again... But without any return, that means that the following will be called many times (actually none because you can't exit from that function).

```
if userInput in "morning" or "night":
    Input2(year)
```

Same error, it should be:

```
if userInput in ["morning", "night"]:
```

or

```
if userInput == "morning" or userInput == "night":
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the sequence of operators. At first, you ask the user for input; afterwards, you print the "Please choose" prompt. So, this prompt won't appear until the user enters the value. The proper way:

```
userInput = raw_input("Please choose either morning or night:")
```

Also, your conditions in `if` statements are incorrect as far as I understand. Refer to Python documentation about `in` and `or` operators.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a prompt in the `raw_input` call:

```
userInput = raw_input("Please choose either morning or night: ")
```

For this logic: `if userInput != "morning" or "night"` You actually want `if userInput != "morning" and userInput != "night"`. Another way to write it is `if userInput not in ('morning', 'night'). Similar logic applies to your your second if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually calling Input1(time) when you run the code? It won't run if you don't call it.

Answer (score -2):

`raw_input()` was renamed to `input()`

From http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html

Comment: ... In Python 3. His code would throw an error if he would use Python 3 and `raw_input`.